# Why does this sequence fail to converge in this space?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

"It might be well to point out that our definition of 'convergent sequence' depends not only on {$p_n$} but also on X; for instance, the sequence {$1/n$} converges in $\Bbb R^1$ (to $0$), but fails to converge in the set of all positive real numbers [with d(x,y)=|x-y|]."

Here why does the sequence {1/n} fail to converge in the set of all positive real numbers [with d(x,y)=|x-y|]?

Comment: Which positive real number do you propose your sequence converge to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero is not a positive real number.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $\{1/n\}$ as you say, converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. We note that if a sequence converges to a number, that number must be unique. So the sequence does not converge to any other number besides $0$. Since $0$ is not a positive real number, our sequence does not converge in the positive reals.